# how to preview video textures?

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, video

I've enabled Preferences/add-ons/ "import images as planes" to import a video as a texture. When I render the animation, everything is fine, but the video won't move neither in the material preview nore in the rendered preview. There, the video is only displayed as a still image. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: what blender version are u using?

Comment: @Chris its the latest version 2.93.1

Comment: @Christoph: did you already try what Emir proposed?

Comment: Oh Yes!!! It was the Auto Refresh button. Now it's fine. THanks a lot, guys!!!